Effects of various building materials on a balanced transmission line?
Is there a significant change in impedance, and/or loss, when balanced transmission line is placed through non-metallic building materials?
e.g., plaster, gypsum wallboard, wood, or cementitious siding?

Just to be sure: when you say "balanced transmission line", you mean something like a ladder line, and not, say, twinax or twisted pair in an Cat.5e network cable?

Yes, most likely 450Ω ladder line.  And as an aside, I'm considering drilling holes to run stainless steel, or aluminum bolts through, calculating the distance between the two bolts using a balanced line calculator, to maintain the 450Ω impedance.   But I am interested to see if anyone has had any challenges with bringing balanced line into a mostly wooden structure, and how they over came the issue.  Obviously keeping a distance from metallic objects, like nails and aluminum gutters, is important, but I figure that's a given in my question.

Agreed, that's a given. Generally, what you describe sounds very feasible – you'll need an estimate for the epsilon of your building material (and you need that to remain constant), but the thinner the wall is relative to wavelength, the less it really matters. And the smaller the structures inside the wall relative to the wavelength, the less it matters whether it's homogeneous or you just use the average epsilon as if it were.
But quite honestly, two holes instead of one, that does sound like a lot of

but truth be told: two holes sounds like more work (and more trouble keeping the wet outside, temperatures inside, and the wall in a reliable state of moisture) than adapting to a shielded transmission line, before and after the wall, and just putting that through a single hole. I haven't done the math, but I imagine two coax cables with their outer conductors touching reliably (so, maybe in a heatshrink tubing?) could make for a reasonable balanced transmission line with much less of the effects of the surrounding material. (really, I'd need to sit down and think this through). Of course, at

low powers, Cat.7 network cabling is 4 pairs, individually shielded, each a balanced transmission line, 100 Ω impedance. (by the way,  the SATA cables you use to connect your desktop PC hard drive, are twinax, also 100 Ω. The "old cables bin" is where one gets one's short run of free twinax line that works reliably up to a couple GHz.)

What's your frequency range? The lower the frequency, the less an impedance discontinuity matters (and vice versa).

@clvrmnky Understood; I did wanted my question to be sufficiently generic without getting into the weeds about my own setup, for the sake of others who may have the same question in the future, but not the same setup.

@Mike Waters Just HF...I would hope to be able to operate a Doublet on 160M to ~12M

@Marcus Müller I found a table that includes "dry" wood, concrete, and a few other substances that might apply to materials used in a residential structure.  I see the issue is the capacitive value of those substances, not any inductive properties, but at that, I see wood can be between 2-6εr which makes the spacing of an 18 gauge wire go from ~22mm in air (εr = 1), and 911mm if εr = 4.  The question then is along what Mike Waters brings up, is there sufficient difference in the very short distance, relative to the wave length being carried, to require making an allowance for this?

well, that's basically the question you get if you forget about the "mechanical" realities of that and just do a Z_0 / Z_wall / Z_0 transmission line transformer, with the the electrical length of Z_wall being short: does turning on the Z_wall circle (in the Smith chart) e.g. for 1/40 of a wavelength make a real difference to you? Don't  know what your tolerances to mismatch is!

@Marcus Müller Very good point.  I see how I can model that on a Smith Chart, and yes, it would likely make very little difference if there is a slight impedance change over a few centimeters, compared to a field that is changing over 10's of meters.

I thank everyone for their input. For anyone who comes across this question, I think the most complete answer is achieved by reading all the posts and comments.

Yes, if the distance between the transmission line and the other object is less than 1 or 2 times the the distance between its conductors, there's likely to be some effect. The effect will be greater the longer the length of transmission line that's near the other object (i.e. if it's just a few inches, it's rarely anything worth thinking about for either loss or impedance purposes, at HF frequencies).
I don't know of any decent models for this stuff, but you can get an idea by searching for various materials together with "permittivity" or "dielectric constant" (which will give you some idea of its effect on impedance) and "loss tangent" (which will similarly inform you about lossiness). Anything with a high moisture content is likely to be lossy, which includes wood most of the time, and probably some plasters, gypsums, and cements some of the time.

Good. Let me see if anyone else has input.  I'll see if I can find a table of permittivity & dielectric constant for various building products, that would require me to make a spacing adjustment when going through these materials.
